# Initialize malloc in zeros instead of using calloc

Tags: c

I want to create dynamic array in the heap using `malloc`.

```
int *c = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
```

The problem is that it is **not** initialized by zero and I'd like avoid using `calloc` as much as I can since I don't know how safe it is.

If I use `calloc`, is it going to do the same `malloc` job?

Comment: `calloc` is 100% safe. Just do `int *c = calloc(5,sizeof(int));` and don't worry. It is designed correctly. It _will_ init to zero, which is what you want. If you don't need init to zero, use `malloc` as it would be a touch faster.

Comment: Whatever made you think `calloc` isnt safe?

Comment: Where on Earth would you get the idea that `calloc` is less safe? It's actually more safe in some circumstances (IIRC, it handles integer overflow properly if the number of elements * the size of each element would overflow a `size_t`; `malloc` can't recognize this because you have to do the multiplication and pass the already overflowed value to it).

Comment: @ShadowRanger the standard is unclear on whether it should handle overflow properly , and some common implementations don't

Comment: @M.M: Oops, I meant to qualify that `calloc` _can_ handle overflow, where the nature of `malloc` precludes even the possibility of handling overflow. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @M.M disagree with "unclear on whether it should handle overflow properly".  Agree some implementations do not handle it well.

Comment: @chux well, `calloc` creates an object, and the standard says that an object cannot exceed `SIZE_MAX`. The standard doesn't say what the behaviour should be of a request to create an object exceeding that size, so it could be argued that it's undefined by omission.

Comment: @M.M Agree about "standard says that an object cannot exceed SIZE_MAX".  But using `calloc()`, code is not making a object exceeding `SIZE_MAX` in size.  It is only allocating memory.  I do agree an object can not have more that `SIZE_MAX` elements.  But a pointer in not an array and does not have `N` elements.

Comment: @M.M  `calloc()` does not allocate an object (one).  Instead "The `calloc` function allocates space for an array of `nmemb` objects, each of whose size
is `size`.

Comment: @chux in C allocating space for an object is the same as creating an object.

Comment: @M.M  Disagree about sameness of `calloc()` and creating an object.  Code can initialize an object and give it an identifier.  Code cannot, by allocating, initialize memory aside from zero nor give it an identifier in which to apply the `sizeof` operator. - which is limited in its response to `SIZE_MAX`.  Although your assertion is a reasonable POV, I do not concur having experience using `calloc()` to allocate space exceeding `SIZE_MAX`.  Was that a compliant platform - I thought so - but it was some time ago.  Suggest making a post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**malloc():**

`malloc()` takes one arguement: the amount of bytes to be allocated. The allocated bytes are **uninitialized.** Hence, their values could be anything from 0-255, or any combination of those numbers. **Don't count on anything!**

*Code Sample:*

```
int *mem = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
```

---

**calloc():**

`calloc()` takes two arguements: the amount of elements to allocate memory for and the amount of memory that needs allocated for each element. It **initializes** each byte to zero.

*Code Sample:*

```
int *mem = calloc(5, sizeof(int));
```

From *The C programming Language* ~ Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie:

> void *calloc(size_t nobj, size_t size)
>   calloc returns a pointer to space for an array of nobj objects,
>   each of size size, or NULL if the request cannot be satisfied.
>   **The space is initialized to zero bytes.**

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

---

**Alternatively, you can initialize memory with `memset()`**

```
#include <string.h> // for memset()

//allocate memory
int *mem = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));

//initialize memory to zeros
memset(mem, 0, 5 * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Thank you. so I should do : `calloc(5 * sizeof(int));` ? I don't get when you said two arguments

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much

Comment: Detail: "It does not initialize the bytes to zero." --> may be it does, maybe it doesn't.  Bytes values are indeterminate.

Comment: @chux: Thanks for the potential erratum. However, from `man calloc`: "the memory is set to 0." Of course I could be misunderstanding the manual or what you're trying to say... I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "Bytes values are indeterminate."

Comment: @chux: Added reference.

Comment: My comment relates to `malloc()`,

Comment: @chux: I see what you mean. However, wouldn't you say that if the byte values are indeterminate, they are not "initialized"? In short, even though the values may occasionally be zeros, I think it's still accurate to say that "malloc does not initialize the bytes to zero." Don't you?

Comment: Yes and no.  Many learners see things like "does not do that" as a specification and are surprised when the system does that when the spec asserts indeterminate values.  Agree answer is accurate - to a degree- yet my thoughts are on how to make it more accurate. UV

Comment: @chux: I've endeavored to clarify the potential misconception.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `calloc()`, it's safe or else why would it be implemented in the standard library and how? It will be presumably more efficient than `malloc()` + `memset()` for large allocations.

Comment: It's more efficient for large allocations (which end up going to the OS directly in ways that the OS guarantees zeroed memory for, so no `memset` is needed at all). For small allocations, it's effectively the same as `malloc`+`memset`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use memset if you want to avoid using calloc for some reason.  you can do it like this:

```
memset (c, 0, 5 * sizeof(int));
```

Don't forget to check the return value from malloc.

Comment: memset is good to use when you're initializing other types of memory.  For example, if you want to initialize a character array to all spaces.